# the wifi driver is not working in Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, 16.04, broadcom

My Broadcom chipset is BCM43142 802.11 b/g/n. I checked with the Software and Updates tab in the System Settings and it showed that I am using a driver sourced from `bcmwl-kernel-source`. But it is still not working.

I had used the `bcmwl-kernel-source` to fix the same issue in Ubuntu 15.10 but this is not working in the Ubuntu 16.04.

The output of `lspci -knn |grep Net -A2` is:

```
08:00.0 network controller [0280]: broadcom corporation bcm43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4: 4365 ] rev 01 
Device name: broadcom bcm43142 802.11bgn 1*1 WiFi adapter + bt 4.0 combo adapter 
Subsystem: Hewlett Packard company bcm43142 802. 11b/g/n [103:2230 ]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem on my HP Stream. For me, the solution was to go to the BIOS menu and disable secure boot manually (even though it may be prompting you to enter a password during installation of the OS or of packages, that does not mean it is disabling secure boot). This allowed my computer to use the bcmwl-kernel-source driver that it listed in the system settings, as you mentioned. I do not know if this is the fix you will need, but it is what worked for me - further info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866640/wifi-issues-on-hp-stream-14-with-broadcom-bcm43142-network-controller-and-no-eth).