# WiFi Issues on HP Stream 14 with Broadcom BCM43142 Network Controller and no Ethernet Port

Tags: drivers, 16.04, wireless, broadcom, hp

I just switched my HP Stream 14 laptop to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from Windows. I have experienced the same problem as many others: I cannot see any wireless networks. Other threads have pointed to the driver as the issue, and I have tried to fix it as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553615/cant-enable-the-proprietary-drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-after-instal) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline/626653#626653), but neither of these worked (I am creating this question because I have yet to find an existing source that can guide me through how to fix my connection issues). It is possible that I did the suggested fixes wrong, as I am relatively new to Ubuntu. Can someone walk me through, step by step, how I can fix this issue? I have spent many hours on it already, and could use some expert help. I have re-installed Ubuntu, so it is the factory version I am working with.

Important info:

```
lspci -nn | grep Network
```

returns

`01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)`

Under "System Settings" > "Software & Updates" > "Additional Drivers", It says

"Broadcom Corporation: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n 
This device is using an alternative driver.
Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (open source)"

(This part makes me think the driver is not the issue).

Additionally, this laptop does not have an ethernet port, so I can only use the USB I used to install Ubuntu and a separate computer with an internet connection.

Comment: Hi Charles, your Broadcom is found and tested on my list of Broadcom cards in http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395 Please verify it works as mentioned there so I can close this question.

Comment: In the guide, it states: "The installation procedure is done... with temporary... Internet access." I do not have this. Later, this is addressed by linking [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline/626653#626653), which is something I have tried to no avail (I linked to it above).

Comment: Hi Charles, keep on reading till the end for the cases of offline work but follow the 4 steps provided. This is what has worked for me but I would need confirmation from your end.

Comment: These steps worked - I had to manually disable secure boot from the BIOS menu first, because it would not disable from the terminal. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As per our comment and as a very rare cases (Thanks to Charles Kocher for the testing). The user can follow this guide [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395) either for OFFLINE installation or ONLINE installation but on both cases they would need to disable Secure Boot.

This is the same case when installing Ubuntu from a LiveUSB / LiveDVD and you select "install 3rd party software and drivers" and the installer asks to disable Secure Boot. It appears this applies to the HP Stream 14 to. I have known about 2 other cases but I see there are more to come. So thank you Charles.